# error: python-dateutil 1.5 is installed but python-dateutil>=2.4.0 is required by set(['vobject'])

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-7

[image]

I am new to OpenERP-7.0 and already installed python-dateutil_2.4.0 version.

How to fix it please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's give you error because of system refer `python-dateutil 1.5` version. Try with uninstall it and remove `.egg`.

For example:

1. uninstall package

   ```
   sudo pip uninstall python-dateutil
   ```
2. remove `.egg` file

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-1.5-py2.7.egg
   ```
3. reinstall it

   ```
   sudo easy_install python-dateutil
   ```

**For Ubuntu:**

1. uninstall python-dateutil and it's dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python-dateutil
   ```
2. purging your config/data too

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-dateutil
   ```
3. reinstall it

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-dateutil
   ```

You may download from here: [python-dateutil 2.4.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.4.2)

Comment: Thanks for you. I try to it and okey.